# CMS to submit contents about a topic, with voting system

Tags: api, cms, voting

Need a CMS with the following specs:

- Allows to upload short contents (text, HTML, JSON etc.) about specific topics.
  E.g. topics: [cats, dogs, birds], people can submit external links to articles or short phrases about any of these.
- Allows to query the topics and contents for a topic via API.
- The admin can moderate the submissions before being published.
- Nice to have: the individual contents can be up / downvoted by logged in users, to assign relevance / sorting. Some contents can't be voted on.
- Social / OpenId user authentication.

It should be a modern, well maintained tech stack, ideally open source but it's not mandatory. It can be free or paid. Not large storage requirements, it's a "niche" use case for a small community.